# sybase ase deferred update mode

Tags: sql-update, query-optimization, sybase, database-performance, sap-ase

I could use some help regarding the optimizer choices for the below update. I expected a direct update, not a deferred update.

In real live this concerns a target table containing ~5M rows being updated from a smaller table with ~200k rows. The deferred update takes quit some time, also because the target table has about 60 columns.

Any suggestions explaining this behavior are very welcome, including suggestions to improve performance of this query. The smaller table can easily be modified, changes to the target table have more impact as it is part of the product datamodel.

Many thanks!

Elroy

```
select @@version --Adaptive Server Enterprise/15.5/EBF 18158 SMP ESD#2/P/X64/Windows Server/asear155/2514/64-bit/OPT/Wed Aug 25 05:39:57 2010

IF OBJECT_ID('test_target') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE test_target
GO
CREATE TABLE test_target  ( 
    id              numeric(15,0) IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    col1            numeric(15,0) NOT NULL,
    col2            char(15) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_test_target PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(id)
    )
LOCK DATAPAGES
go
insert into test_target select 1, '123'
insert into test_target select 1, '456'
go

IF OBJECT_ID('test_from') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE test_from
GO
CREATE TABLE test_from  ( 
    from_id         numeric(15,0) NOT NULL,
    from_col2    char(15) NOT NULL
    )
LOCK ALLPAGES
GO
insert into test_from select 1,'1'
go
create unique clustered index k1 on test_from (from_id)
go

set showplan on
go

update test_target 
set col2 = from_col2
from test_target
join test_from on from_id = id 

set showplan off
go

QUERY PLAN FOR STATEMENT 1 (at line 1).


 STEP 1
     The type of query is UPDATE.

   4 operator(s) under root

     |ROOT:EMIT Operator (VA = 4)
     |
     |   |UPDATE Operator (VA = 3)
     |   |  The update mode is deferred.
     |   |
     |   |   |NESTED LOOP JOIN Operator (VA = 2) (Join Type: Inner Join)
     |   |   |
     |   |   |   |SCAN Operator (VA = 0)
     |   |   |   |  FROM TABLE
     |   |   |   |  test_from
     |   |   |   |  Table Scan.
     |   |   |   |  Forward Scan.
     |   |   |   |  Positioning at start of table.
     |   |   |   |  Using I/O Size 16 Kbytes for data pages.
     |   |   |   |  With LRU Buffer Replacement Strategy for data pages.
     |   |   |
     |   |   |   |SCAN Operator (VA = 1)
     |   |   |   |  FROM TABLE
     |   |   |   |  test_target
     |   |   |   |  Using Clustered Index.
     |   |   |   |  Index : PK_test_target
     |   |   |   |  Forward Scan.
     |   |   |   |  Positioning by key.
     |   |   |   |  Keys are:
     |   |   |   |    id ASC
     |   |   |   |  Using I/O Size 16 Kbytes for index leaf pages.
     |   |   |   |  With LRU Buffer Replacement Strategy for index leaf pages.
     |   |   |   |  Using I/O Size 16 Kbytes for data pages.
     |   |   |   |  With LRU Buffer Replacement Strategy for data pages.
     |   |
     |   |  TO TABLE
     |   |  test_target
     |   |  Using I/O Size 16 Kbytes for data pages.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, to get a `direct` update you need to have the table being updated come first in the query plan ... though, ideally, in this case the optimizer should be able to figure out that a) you're joining the tables based on 2 unique indexes (ie, guaranteed to have a 1-to-1 match) so b) a `direct` update would be preferable.

There are a few ways to get a `direct` update ... and assuming you don't want to wrap the query in a pair of `set forceplan on/off` commands, and you don't want to add an abstract query plan (AQP - optimizer hints), you could try something like:

```
-- for test purposes, make sure optimizer isn't re-using query plan from previous test run
set statement_cache off
go

set showplan on
go

update test_target

                 -- push the join into a sub-query
set    tt.col2 = (select tf1.from_col2 from test_from tf1 where tf1.from_id = tt.id)

from   test_target tt

where  -- only process tt rows that have a match in tf2
       exists(select 1 from test_from tf2 where tf2.from_id = tt.id)
go

STEP 1
    The type of query is UPDATE.

    8 operator(s) under root

   |ROOT:EMIT Operator (VA = 8)
   |
   |   |UPDATE Operator (VA = 7)
   |   |  The update mode is direct.
   |   |
   |   |   |SQFILTER Operator (VA = 6) has 2 children.
   |   |   |
   |   |   |   |NESTED LOOP JOIN Operator (VA = 3) (Join Type: Inner Join)
   |   |   |   |
   |   |   |   |   |GROUP SORTED Operator (VA = 1)
   |   |   |   |   |Distinct
   |   |   |   |   |
   |   |   |   |   |   |SCAN Operator (VA = 0)
   |   |   |   |   |   |  FROM TABLE
   |   |   |   |   |   |  test_from
   |   |   |   |   |   |  tf2
   |   |   |   |   |   |  Table Scan.
   |   |   |   |   |   |  Forward Scan.
   |   |   |   |   |   |  Positioning at start of table.
   |   |   |   |   |   |  Using I/O Size 2 Kbytes for data pages.
   |   |   |   |   |   |  With LRU Buffer Replacement Strategy for data pages.
   |   |   |   |
   |   |   |   |   |SCAN Operator (VA = 2)
   |   |   |   |   |  FROM TABLE
   |   |   |   |   |  test_target
   |   |   |   |   |  tt
   |   |   |   |   |  Using Clustered Index.
   |   |   |   |   |  Index : PK_test_target
   |   |   |   |   |  Forward Scan.
   |   |   |   |   |  Positioning by key.
   |   |   |   |   |  Keys are:
   |   |   |   |   |    id ASC
   |   |   |   |   |  Using I/O Size 2 Kbytes for index leaf pages.
   |   |   |   |   |  With LRU Buffer Replacement Strategy for index leaf pages.
   |   |   |   |   |  Using I/O Size 2 Kbytes for data pages.
   |   |   |   |   |  With LRU Buffer Replacement Strategy for data pages.
   |   |   |
   |   |   |  Run subquery 1 (at nesting level 1).
   |   |   |
   |   |   |  QUERY PLAN FOR SUBQUERY 1 (at nesting level 1 and at line 11).
   |   |   |
   |   |   |   Correlated Subquery.
   |   |   |   Subquery under an EXPRESSION predicate.
   |   |   |
   |   |   |   |SCALAR AGGREGATE Operator (VA = 5)
   |   |   |   |  Evaluate Ungrouped ONCE AGGREGATE.
   |   |   |   |
   |   |   |   |   |SCAN Operator (VA = 4)
   |   |   |   |   |  FROM TABLE
   |   |   |   |   |  test_from
   |   |   |   |   |  tf1
   |   |   |   |   |  Using Clustered Index.
   |   |   |   |   |  Index : k1
   |   |   |   |   |  Forward Scan.
   |   |   |   |   |  Positioning by key.
   |   |   |   |   |  Keys are:
   |   |   |   |   |    from_id ASC
   |   |   |   |   |  Using I/O Size 2 Kbytes for data pages.
   |   |   |   |   |  With LRU Buffer Replacement Strategy for data pages.
   |   |   |
   |   |   |  END OF QUERY PLAN FOR SUBQUERY 1.
   |   |
   |   |  TO TABLE
   |   |  test_target
   |   |  Using I/O Size 2 Kbytes for data pages.
```

Whether or not this is better/faster than a deferred update will depend on the volume of rows that have to be scanned from tt plus the number of joins to tf1 and tf2.

Also keep in mind that no amount of tricks may help if you've got an trigger on the table, or you find yourself updating an indexed column.

Comment: I've tried both the forceplan and subquery approach and got the direct update. Unfortunately the direct update was slower/less efficient on production data, so I'll stick to the original query. Thanks much for your effort and clear explanation!

Answer (score 0):

If there's a "worst answer" award you can give it to me.  I used to work at Sybase as a Senior Consultant, and I came to the conclusion that direct update isn't worth the time to make it work.  If your concern is performance, I would suggest using an application or stored procedure to perform the update in batches.  Put an ID on the update source table and update where ID is 1 to 5000, 2 to 5001, and so forth.  My personal experience is that this gives you a better bang for the buck.

Also, have you checked the rules for a direct update?  They are looser than they were in my day, where any NULL or variable-size (varchar) column being updated made the update deferred, but still fairly restrictive: http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00743.1502/html/queryprocessing/queryprocessing29.htm .

I'm new here - should this have been posted differently, since it's not actually the requested solution?